# Can't break the while loop

Tags: java, loops

```
public void play () {
    int anInteger;
    //guess return code
    int code;

    while (true) {
        String input=null;
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter an integer");

        if (input == "-1") {
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, input);
            System.exit(0);
            break;
        } else {
            if (input==null) {
                 System.exit(0);
            } else if (input.isEmpty()) {
                 continue;
            } else {
                anInteger = Integer.parseInt(input);
                code = this.oneGuess (anInteger);
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, anInteger);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I want, if the user enter `-1`, show the program will not prompt the message box any more. Above is the code I have come up with, so far. Why it doesn't work?

Comment: you are waiting "1" in your code to be entered to break the loop, not "-1"

Comment: typing error............

Comment: i would also advise you to use a suitable IDE for development (eclipse, netbeans, etc) cos writing == instead of .equals() shd show you a warning, which you can correct yourself.

Answer (score 7):

String comparisons does NOT work with "==" operator, use "String.equals(Object)" function

```
input.equals("-1");
```

Better way would be

```
"-1".equals(input);
```

as it also takes care of null input

Comment: +1 for turning it around and including the check for null

Answer (score 5):

You are comparing strings, which are objects, with the `==` operator, which checks whether two object references refer to the same object instance. Instead you should use the `equals` method for comparing them.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between comparing with `==` and `equals`. The first compares pointers, the latter contents. That is probably your issue.

Answer (score -1):

You compare Strings with ==, which creates a problem. You can have many different String-Objects which all show "-1". The == tests, if you have exactly the same object on the left and right side. You want to know, if the objects on the left and right sie have an equal content.

Better try

```
input.equalsIgnoreCase("-1");
```

EDIT: To answer the comment: input.equalsIgnoreCase("-1") is the same as input.equals("-1") in the case of "-1" as there are no uppercase/lowercase letters in "-1". However, I prefer equalsIgnoreCase in the case of Strings, because it is defined on String, rather than on Object. Still, as the equals-definition is overridden for the String class, it works too in this example and "ignoreCase" is not needed.

Comment: You might like to add an example of when `input.equalsIgnoreCase("-1")` and  `input.equals("-1")` are not the same thing. ;)